# Syntax error using jQuery validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm getting a syntax error using jquery validate plugin. I want to target classes and not field names which is why I am using the following syntax:

```
$("#myFormID").validate({        
    $('.optionSelectClass').rules("add", {
        required: true
    });       

    $('.optionSelectClass').messages("add", { 
        required: "Please select an option"    
    });

});
```

Firebug console says missing : after property id

Any idea's?

Answer (score 1):

When defining an object using object literal syntax, don't put an `;` after each `key: value` pair declaration:

```
{
    required: true
}
```

Object literals are declared via comma separated `key: value` pair declarations:

```
{
    required: true, // note the comma
    minLength: 4,   // note the comma
    maxLength: 10   // note _no_ comma; this will throw a SyntaxError in IE
}
```

Comment: O yes of course, thanks. I took out the semi colons, but I still have the same syntax error in console.